# How to select only cells in one row in a jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have a JTable consisting of multiple rows and columns. I want to make the cells selectable, but only in one row at a time. So for example, when I click on the cell in third row and the fifth column, I can pull the mouse to the left or right and select more cells, but only in this specific row and not in the row above or below.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`setSelectionMode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionMode%28int%29) method from `ListSelectionModel` interface, and set the selection mode to [`ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_SELECTION).

This will configure `JTable` to work with *one row at a time* selection, blocking selection of multiple rows.

To select single cells, combine the above with [`setColumnSelectionAllowed(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#setColumnSelectionAllowed%28boolean%29) on `TableColumnModel`, and you should get what you need.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but now I can only select one cell. I wanted to be able to select multiple cells in one row, but not the whole row. I now played around with `setColumnSelectionAllowed(), setRowSelectionAllowed()` and `setCellSelectionEnabled()`, but no combination seems to do the trick.

Comment: Hah, it seems you need to implement your own `ListSelectionModel` then.

Comment: Actually, take a look at the [`DefaultListSelectionModel`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.java#DefaultListSelectionModel) source code. Especially the methods that operate on _selection interval_. Perhaps a slight change in that code (like _not clearing_ the existing selection if it is in the same row) will do what you need.

Comment: Now I extended the `DefaultListSelectionModel` and overrode the `setSelectionInteval()`, added a new constant for the new selection case and overrode the constructor to get it to work. The modified `setSelectionInterval()` method now looks like this:

`public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
   if(selectionMode == SINGLE_ROW_MULTIPLE_CELLS_SELECTION)
    index1 = index0;
   super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
  }`